# User Session in java desktop application

Tags: java, spring

would like to ask you, i want to use user session in a java desktop application to store variables so it can be used across pages after googling it i found the httpsession or servelet but i think it can be used in project related to web development.

i thought that i can create a table in my database and when a user logged in i store his informations in that table and when hi logged out i just delete them from the table but i think there is a better solution to this problem
so Is there a way to store the user informatiops (session) (or something similar) so that i could access it through the entire desktop application?

thank you in advance.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the solution you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global static map with the user ID as the map key and the user info as the value, and remove it from the map when the user logs out.